PHP libvips convert HEIC to JPG
I have the following code in PHP that is responsible for taking in a file and then converting it from HEIC -> JPG using the https://www.libvips.org/API/current/VipsForeignSave.html#vips-jpegsave library
// Write image to temp file
$raw_photo = $request->getBody();
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, $raw_photo);

// Get the file path
$temp_meta = stream_get_meta_data($temp);
$temp_path = $temp_meta['uri'];
    
// Create image using Vips library
$image = Image::newFromFile($temp_path);
         
// Convert to JPG
$image->jpegsave($temp_path . '.jpg');        
// $image->writeToFile($temp_path . '.jpg');      <-- I also tried this, but didn't work

This code works and I am getting an image returned of .jpg type confirmed by Finder
However, when using other applications like Slack or https://www.checkfiletype.com/ it says the file type is still HEIF:


Is there something I am missing here?

Asked and answered here https://github.com/libvips/php-vips/discussions/184
